# Botany related question: liverwort sporophyte

Tags: botany

Is perianth part of the sporophyte or gametophyte in liverworts (Marchantiophyta)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be a part of the gametophyte because it is formed from the fusion of leaves (which are haploid) and protects the archegonium and the developing capsule.

It also can be logically thought out. Since it develops before the sporophyte forms , it should be part of the gametophyte.

Comment: [Here](http://books.google.de/books?id=2LYOIs-7sNYC&pg=PA117) it is stated explicitly.